# Is ng-option animation aware in angulajs 1.4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-animations

I'm trying to use ngAnimate(v1.4) for ng-option but I couldn't find any animate event for it in angularjs documentation. Does anyone know if ng-option directive animation aware? Can anyone provide a link for reference or an example?

I'm trying to add animation to select2 dropdown using angularjs ngAnimate. But not able to do so. See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashishU/o6ojj9xs/

I'm not sure which ngAnimate event to add the animation to. It doesn't seem to work.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <select class="dd1" ng-model="dropDown1" ng-options="value for value in         dropDownValue1">
  <option value="">{{dropDownName1}}</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    angular.module("testApp", ["ngAnimate"]).controller("testCtrl",     function($scope) {
  $scope.dropDownName1 = "animateDD1";
  $scope.dropDownValue1 = ['This', 'IS', 'Animation', 'For', 'DD1'];

  $(".dd1").select2();

});
```

**CSS**

```
 @keyframes openDD {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes closeDD {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.dd2.ng-enter {
  animation: openDD 2s;
}

.dd2.ng-leave {
  animation: closeDD 1s;
}
```

Comment: post what you want and what you have tried ....

Comment: I have added more info